# Apache Superset on Mobile

Tags: mobile, apache-superset

Does anyone know if you can expose a superset or chart on a mobile device? Has anyone explored it?

I have researched github and stackoverflow but have not seen anything posted.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 considerations here:

1. How to run Superset (the service / code)

Superset is primarily a Python backend application and typically runs on your computer locally or in a cloud environment (like on Amazon Web Services or Microsoft Azure). If you're running Superset locally (e.g. via Docker Compose), you can navigate to localhost:8088 and the Superset backend will serve you frontend code to your web browser. If you're running the Superset backend in a cloud environment, then you'll need to do extra configuration in your cloud environment to expose it safely to a publicly accessible port (which can then be mapped to a web domain you purchased, like "awesomesuperset.com").

2. How to access charts from a mobile device

Once you've configured Superset to be accessible through a port (that maps to a URL your mobile device can access), you'll be able to navigate to that URL from your mobile web browser.

Superset, at the moment, unfortunately isn't designed for mobile devices. There's been some informal discussion about this in the community, but it's a big undertaking!

**So even if you got this all working, I'd generally recommend accessing Superset's UI from a laptop or desktop computer!**

Answer (score 0):

Superset in its current state is not designed for mobile form factor. However you can cleverly make use of the grid, you can build a simple mobile ready dashboard. I had created a simple status dashboard for mobile viewing, just using the **Big Number chart, pie chart and simple line chart**. Not other fancy charts were used and indeed the line chart was limited to 10-15 data points. Just sharing if this helps you.

**Note:** *this would not be a interactive page.*

Answer (score 0):

**For superset as a whole;**

It has, to some extend, **some** responsiveness but not %100, i.e. the menus will behave according to the media width or height as your window resizes etc. But dashboards will not be responsive.

**To display a single chart/dashboard in a native mobile application;**

Get an authentication token from the api, and then use (&standalone=true) query parameter in the call to superset. Then the web view (or other browser controls) will display the chart or dashboard.

**To display a single chart/dashboard in a web page;**

For this, you will need superset to run in an iframe and put a query parameter (&standalone=true). But this is not automatic in its current state. What ever configuration you do, you will not pass even the login screen. To overcome this,  session manager must be changed ("app.session_interface") to be able load session state from the URL, not from cookies, in a secure way. [This](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-stupid-ideas) can help you start. But bare in mind that, this is not a fully secure method. Meaning, if the URL you are using to get the dash or chart contains a session state generated by an admin, that means you are giving a free pass to everything in superset.